# What’s the most suitable programming language for AI development?

Tags: python, javascript

For the past couple of years I’ve been learning how to use Python to script.  But I would like to start getting into scripting more things like computers and AI.  So, with that said, and please no hate, what in your opinion would be best to script things like that?  For example - [JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript?wprov=sfti1) or [c#/c+/c++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C++_Programming_Language?wprov=sfti1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Disclaimer: this is massively subjective topic, and below is just my opinion.***

---

I would say it depends on your focus. You could do work in these areas with any major programming language, but some have better suited capabilities and/or better support from a community.

My biased and very simple answer would be to use **Python** for basically everything, and learn **C++** for times when performance is important. And then, if you get really serious, you'll need to learn **CUDA** (extensions to C++ to programme directly for Nvidia GPUs). If you are proficient at Python and C++, there isn't really anything you couldn't do.

### In summary

- If you want to do research, you could probably do everything with just Python. There are libraries such a NumPy/PyTorch/Tensorflow which do all the heavy lifting for you.
- If you want to go the way of robotics and embedded hardware/software, you'll likely need C/C++.
- If you want to make models to deploy in a browser, perhaps Javascript would be useful.